# Вопрос по vk sdk

Tags: android

Что бы осуществлять некоторые запросы официального vk sdk api на андроид, нужен параметр audio_id. Но в VKApiConst такого нет. Кто знает как его передать.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В запрос можно писать "audio_id" вместо VKApiConst.AUDIO_ID - которого нет.
Например:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("audio.add", VKParameters.from("audio_id", "197010009", "owner_id", "6492"));
```

Comment: Параметры запроса не все, просто написал для примера)

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло